# performing an snmpget in python

Tags: python, snmp

I am trying to run a simple snmpget command using python. For example at the CLI I am using the below command. I want to know how to run this in python and store it in a variable.

```
snmpget -c public -v1 192.168.1.3 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.17
```

output: iso.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.17 = Gauge32: 100000000

Comment: What do you mean "store it in a variable"? What format do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @aruisdante  I updated my question  with the CLI output.  I'm fine with this format I just don't know of how to do a snmpget  in python.

Comment: Yes, but when you say "store it in a variable", what form do you expect that variable to be? A single string containing anything written to stdout by `snmpget`?

Comment: @aruisdante yes storing as a string would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) modules check_output function

```
from subprocess import check_output
out = check_output(["ls", "-l"])
print out
```

General format: `check_output(["cmd", "argument1", "argument2",..."argumentN"])`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do snmpget it in java with snmp4j. In python,there is library called [snimpy](https://github.com/vincentbernat/snimpy) and [SNMP library for Python](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/). There are examples in this post [Snimpy: SNMP & Python](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2013-snimpy.html).